# ImportXML extract paginated table into Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I would like to scrape this table url is:

https://www.londonstockexchange.com/indices/ftse-aim-all-share/constituents/table?page=1

As you can see its currently 39 pages but this can change so it's dynamic. Can someone please provide guidance on how to import it into google sheets. I have come up with the following so far:

```
=IMPORTXML(https://www.londonstockexchange.com/indices/ftse-aim-all-share/constituents/table?page=1", "table",1)
```

But it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

The website you are trying to scrape is loading the table dynamically. IMPORTXML is used only for static content.
Your best bet would be to write your own script to parse it, or to find a paid service.